How do we know the dual pairing between Lp spaces is well defined?
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $X \in L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ and $Y\in L^q(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$. Then the dual pair betweent these spaces is defined as $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle:L^p \times L^q \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ via
$$ \langle X, Y\rangle := \int_{\Omega} X(\omega) Y(\omega) d\mu(\omega) $$
My question: How do we know that this integral is well defined, i.e., that we cannot get any type of expression like $\infty - \infty$?

I dont think it has anything to do with the question you cited.

What have you tried?  Why do you think it could give $\infty - \infty$? Do you know Hölder's inequality?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality

As long as $q$ is supposed to be the conjugate of $p$ (i.e. $\frac1p + \frac1q = 1$) and $p \geq 1$ then the integral of the product is well-defined thanks to Hölder's inequality, which holds for all measure spaces.

Hi yes I mean that q is the conjugate of p. Can you elaborate on how it follows from hoelders ineequality?

@guest1 Hölder's inequality tells you that the integrals you're interested with are all finite, so that the dual mapping you're considering is well-defined.

@BrunoB: This holds for $1\leq p\leq\infty$. For $0<p<1$ the duality is different.

@Mittens Ah, I see. But, to my defense, OP didn't say which $p$ they were taking so I just assumed $p \geq 1$ as it's the most common.
